# Writing a python code for email validation : it is not working in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext

```
email = input("Enter your email: ")

k,j,d=0, 0, 0

if len(email)>=6:
    if email[0].isalpha():
        if ("@" in email) and (email.count()==1):
            if (email[-4] ==".") ^ (email[-3] =="."):
                for i in email:
                    if i==i.isspace():
                        k=1
                    elif i.isalpha():
                         if i == i.upper():  
                             j = 1
                    elif i.isdigit():
                        continue
                    elif i =="_" or i =="." or i =="@":
                        continue
                    if k==1 or j==1 or d==1:
                        print("Wrong email 5")
            else:
                print("Wrong email 4")     
        else:
            print("Wrong email 3")
    else:
        print("Wrong email 2")
else:
    print("Wrong Email 1")
```

I have written the code for email validation. Then run the code in sublime text by command + B. It asks for email input when I write the input then press enter. It does not show anything, neither right nor wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running it from your terminal? As much as I know, the Sublime Text output window doesn't return results after accepting the first user input. Open a terminal session, CD into the folder containing your python file and run `python filename.py`

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names than `k, j, d`.

Comment: `if i == i.upper():` can be written more simply as `if i.isupper():`

Comment: Use `True` and `False` for boolean values, not `1` and `0`.